# Oracle connection from Squirrel SQL

Tags: oracle, client

I am trying to set up Squirrel SQL for the first time on my Ubuntu Desktop. Here is the SQLPlus command I use to connect to my DB:

```
 sqlplus64 "user/pw@pashratgdb01.lex.bb.com:1876/atgpen1.lex.bb.com"
```

So I try to set this up in Squirrel SQL as follows with the Oracle Thin Driver:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@pashratgdb01.lex.bb.com:1876:atgpen1.lex.bb.com"
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor


at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:202)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:132)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$100(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$2.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:115)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor


at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:171)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$000(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$1.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:104)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor


at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:133)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:167)
... 7 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor


at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:275)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:264)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
... 12 more
```

Comment: Are you sure the listener is setup to use the fqdn ?

Comment: @Phil I don't understand the question? I can attach to it from SQL Plus. Is there an additional setting I need to attach to it from Squirrel?

Comment: @The Thom i guess there should have' /' instead of ':' .`1876/atgpen1.lex.bb.com`

Comment: @The Thom: provide the output of `lsnrctl status` command from your database server.

Comment: @JSapkota I don't have access to the server.:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original connection string:

```
sqlplus64 "user/pw@pashratgdb01.lex.bb.com:1876/atgpen1.lex.bb.com"
```

This specifices `atgpen1.lex.bb.com` as a **service name**. The JDBC syntax you used specifies a **SID**. Service name identifies a service within a database. SID identifies an instance within a database. Those two are not the same.

Instead of this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@pashratgdb01.lex.bb.com:1876:atgpen1.lex.bb.com"
```

Use this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//pashratgdb01.lex.bb.com:1876/atgpen1.lex.bb.com"
```